# Azure - Unable To Get SQL Azure Invitation Code!

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

#### Scenario

I'm trying to convert my Silverlight Business Application over to the cloud with the help of Azure. I have been following [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/brada/archive/2009/08/21/business-apps-example-for-silverlight-3-rtm-and-net-ria-services-july-update-part-23-azure.aspx) link from Brad Abrams blog.

Both the links to Windows Azure and SQL Azure crash out in Google Chrome, they work in Internet Explorer, but it's literally one of the worst user experiences I've ever had.

#### The Problem

I'm asked to sign in to Microsoft connect with my Live ID.
I do so, I'm then asked to register; I do so.
I'm then sent a verification email which I verify.
I'm then signed out!
When I sign back in, it repeats the process....

Any suggestions for making this work?

#### Edit/Update:

Finally managed to get signed up/in to connect. From here I was able to get hold of an invitation code to Windows Azure. Now I need an invitation code for SQL Azure. I cannot see ANYWHERE that advertises a way of getting this SQL Azure code, the only thing that I have seen is some text saying that there "may be a delay" in receiving codes due to volume of interest, which quite frankly I find hard to believe.........

It's so far been 3 days now. This officially sucks!

If I have any more news I'll post back here.

Comment: I can only you offer my sympathies

Comment: @Nosrama: I need them too, I couldn't figure out how this damned thing works either!

Comment: I think that the Microsoft verification system is failing to send emails to certain domains. We had a similar problem trying to send to a work address. I created a new LiveID connected to a Hotmail address and the verification email came through. Another colleague has the same problem. We can only assume that there is a problem with live.com and our domain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I eventually gave up and emailed the support team moaning about the poor service, got an email invitation code about a day later :-D

Answer (score 0):

Let me assure you that the Windows Azure Portal itself works fine under Chrome... Connect however doesn't.

I'm not sure at what point of the process you're getting stuck.  Is it registering for Connect?  Or have you gotten far enough that you're filling in a survey to get access to Windows Azure?

If it's as early as registering for Connect, I would contact Connect Support: https://connect.microsoft.com/Main/help/emailsupport.aspx?Category=3.

Answer (score 0):

Thats funny. I have just received an SQL Azure October CTP invitation that doesn't work.
But after 3 weeks i still dont have a Windows Azure invitation code. From where Im standing, the Azure registration process appears to be a jumbled mess.

Answer (score 0):

As of Jan 4th SQL Azure (as well as Windows Azure) is now open to all users to register and SQL Azure no longer require tokens.  For more details on this please see the [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/ssds/archive/2010/01/04/9943474.aspx).